# Запутался в Atmel Studio. От языка С в Atmel studio только синтаксис?

Tags: микроконтроллеры, avr

Начал изучать программирование микроконтроллеров. И при виде команды PORTB или DDRC впал в ступор. Разве такие команды есть в языке C. Как это всё работает? Начал искать курсы по прорграммированию МК с нуля, тоже нормального ничего не нашёл. Помогите. От языка С в Atmel studio только синтаксис? Я ничего не понимаю.

Comment: PORTB - имя адреса памяти в которое вы записываете значение. Этот адрес отвечает за состояние выводов порта B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PORTB или DDRC - это не "команды", это целочисленные константы, значения которых определены в хедер-файле, соответствующем выбранной модели контроллера. В данном случае это адрес порта ввода/вывода и адрес регистра, определяющего "направление" данных (ножка конфигурируется на вход или на выход - Data DiRection). Записывая / читая значения в порт B вы изменяете логические уровни на соответствующих пинах, а изменяя состояние DDR регистра вы переопределяете работу пинов как входов / выходов. Значения этих констант для каждой модели контроллера свои, поэтому чтобы не заставлять программиста помнить их или писать в коде магические числа, хедер-файл каждой модели содержит в себе дефайны всех необходимых констант. Также это помогаает при портировании существующего кода на другие модели контроллеров. Этих констант достаточно много - можете посмотреть содержимое файла и почитать документацию. Кстати, при программировании на ассемблере подключаются тот же файл дефайнов, и аргументы asm-инструкций содержат те же самые имена и аббревиатуры.

Comment: Можете скинуть ссылку на документацию или где изучить программирование микроконтроллеров на C.

Comment: Даташиты на конкретные модели МК в свободном доступе в сети, шаблоны при создании нового проекта в Atmel Studio, ну и море литературы, включая русскоязычную - тот же Евстифеев (хотя когда читал его, обнаруживал один в один скопипасченные разделы из мануалов/даташитов)